# CAN Bus programming/control of car's control units?

Tags: can-bus, bus

I'm beginning to learn about programming cars.  I read up on CAN programming and just need to know where i can find information about the control units of each car model.

For example:
I wanna start programming/controlling a 01 chevy blazer.   How do i find a list of the control units inside the car, and more importantly, where do i find the information like each unit's address and it's own specific communication protocol (paraphrase: how do i find out what to write in the data field to get the doors to lock or unlock)

in short I know how to communicate with the control units, i just don't know what to say to them

Comment: This question is far too broad for SO. In addition, it can probably not be answered because no car is the same and the data format on all the various vehicle buses out there is usually not public information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official documentation on this topic since working with cars internal CAN buses (medium- and high-speed) **could be dangerous**.

I suppose the only way to obtain such information is to be an after-market development company. In this case you will be able (after lot time of negotiations) to have info on particular units/messages. So it's definitely not a case for private retrofitting projects.

Basically you could connect to a CAN bus using appropriate adapter and do reverse engineering. Some of data could be easily found (like indicators, head light etc) but obtaining some information is practically impossible (for example fuel level).
Also keep in mind the data could coded using shifting values as well as multipliers.

Comment: True!! Avoid doing this as you may end up hurting yourself!!